# Is there a formula in Excel that allows me to apply another formula to a section ten rows down?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 43 different tables of a plate reading. I have placed samples in triplicates of a 96-well plate.

Here is an example of just two tables:

[image]

My sample 1 is B2:B4 on the excel sheet, my sample 2 is C2:C4, (...), and my sample 12 is M2:M4. For now, I'd like to focus on creating a formula for the top three rows of each table. I am taking the average of my samples at each different time frame.

I'd like to apply a formula that shifts this 'average' formula down 10 cells to the next table, so at time=30, my sample 1 is B12:14.

So at time=0, my sample 1 = average(0.111+0.106+0.103). At time=30, my sample 1=average(0.131+0.126+0.12).

It would look something like this:

[image]

Again, I have to apply the equation over 43 other readings, but every table is equidistant so I'd like to use a formula that recalls the first formula (average), and applies it to another table by shifting the cells down 10 units.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,ROW($B$2:$B$4)+(ROW(A1)*10-10)))` copied down